# Removing content of a column based on number of occurences

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file (; seperated) with data like this

```
111111121;000-000.1;000-000.2
111111211;000-000.1;000-000.2
111112111;000-000.1;000-000.2
111121111;000-000.1;000-000.2
111211111;000-000.1;000-000.2
112111111;000-000.1;000-000.2
121111112;000-000.2;020-000.8
121111121;000-000.2;020-000.8
121111211;000-000.2;020-000.8
121113111;000-000.3;000-200.2
211111121;000-000.1;000-000.2
```

I would like to remove any $3 that has less than 3 occurences, so the outcome would be like

```
111111121;000-000.1;000-000.2
111111211;000-000.1;000-000.2
111112111;000-000.1;000-000.2
111121111;000-000.1;000-000.2
111211111;000-000.1;000-000.2
112111111;000-000.1;000-000.2
121111112;000-000.2;020-000.8
121111121;000-000.2;020-000.8
121111211;000-000.2;020-000.8
121113111;000-000.3
211111121;000-000.1;000-000.2
```

That is, only $3 got deleted, as it had only a single occurence

Sadly I am not really sure if (thus how) this could be done relatively easily (as doing the =COUNT.IF matching, and manuel delete in Excel feels quite embarrassing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{cnt[$3]++;next} cnt[$3]<3{sub(/;[^;]+$/,"")} 1' file file
111111121;000-000.1;000-000.2
111111211;000-000.1;000-000.2
111112111;000-000.1;000-000.2
111121111;000-000.1;000-000.2
111211111;000-000.1;000-000.2
112111111;000-000.1;000-000.2
121111112;000-000.2;020-000.8
121111121;000-000.2;020-000.8
121111211;000-000.2;020-000.8
121113111;000-000.3
211111121;000-000.1;000-000.2
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{cnt[$3]++;next} {print (cnt[$3]<3 ? $1 FS $2 : $0)}' file file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the elegant solution ! (and I am indeed terribly sorry for my late reply...)

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner can help, it processes the file twice:

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{a[$3]++;next}a[$3]<3{NF--}7' file file
```

Comment: YMMV with `NF--` as that's undefined behavior per POSIX so different awks will do different things with it (most likely ignore it or remove the last field).

Answer (score 1):

Though that awk solutions are the best in terms of performance, your goal could be also achieved with something like this:

```
while IFS=" " read a b;do 
  if [[ "$a" -lt "3" ]];then 
    sed -i "s/$b//" b.txt
  fi
done <<<"$(cut -d";" -f3 b.txt |sort |uniq -c)"
```

Operation is based on the output of cut which counts occurrences.

```
$cut -d";" -f3 b.txt |sort |uniq -c
      7 000-000.2
      1 000-200.2
      3 020-000.8
```

Above works for editing source file in place, so keep a back up for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can feed the file twice to awk. On the first run you gather a statistic that you use in the second run:

**script.awk**

```
FNR == NR { stats[ $3 ]++
            next
          }

          { if( stats[$3] < 3) print $1 $2
            else print
          }
```

Run it like this: `awk -F\; -f script.awk yourfile yourfile` .

The condition `FNR == NR` is true during processing of the first filename given to awk. The `next` statement skips the second block.

Thus the second block is only used for processing the second filename given to awk (which is here the same as the first filename).